# Python and numpy : subtracting line by line a 2-dim array from a 1-dim array

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy

In python, I wish to subtract line by line a 2-dim array from a 1-dim array.

I know how to do it with a 'for' loop and indexes but I suppose it may be quicker to use numpy functions. However I did not find a way to do it. Here is an example with a 'for' loop :

```
from numpy import *
x=array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])
y=array([20,10])
j=array([0, 1])
a=zeros([2,5])
for i in j :
...     a[i]=y[i]-x[i]
```

And here is an example of something that does not work, replacing the 'for' loop by this:

```
a=y[j]-x[j,i]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Dou you have suggestions ?

Comment: As a suggestion, I would avoid making a list variable named `j`. Syntax-wise this is OK, but most programmers reserve the letters `i,j,k` for the counters in a loop, leading to some possible confusion here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `y-x` have the respective shapes `(2) (2,5)`. To do proper broadcasting, you'll need shapes `(2,1) (2,5)`. We can do this with `.reshape` as long as the number of elements are preserved:

```
y.reshape(2,1) - x
```

Gives:

```
array([[19, 18, 17, 16, 15],
   [ 4,  3,  2,  1,  0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y[:,newaxis] - x
```

should work too. The (little) comparative benefit is then you pay attention to the dimensions themselves, instead of the sizes of dimensions.