# Python: Iterating on the lines and columns of an array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a simple and efficient way to iterate on an matrix (2D array) by lines and columns. Using Python.

I have 3 2D-matrices of the same size: one containing x-coordinates, one for y-coordinates, and one containing the value for some data (temperature actually) at these coordinates.

I would like to iterate on every element of the 'data' matrix, but by keeping track of the current line and column, because I then need to look for the equivalent value in the 'x' and 'y' matrices.

To be clearer, I would write it like that in Matlab:

```
for i = 1:nb_line
    for j = 1:nb_column
        if data(i,j) ~= 0
            <operations using x[i,j] and y[i,j]>
        end
    end
end
```

In Python, I was thinking in doing it like that:

```
for line in data:
    for elt in line:
        if not elt == 0:
            <operations>
```

My problem is that I am loosing track of my current position in the array, and hence cannot call x[i,j] or y[i,j]...

What is the easiest way to do that?
Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT: My code now looks as follows.

`DATA`, `LAT` and `LON` are netCDF4.variables, which kinda look like 2-D masked arrays, respectively containing a geographical parameter (temperature, elevation, whatever...), its latitude and its longitude.

I want to project this data on a regular latitude/longitude grid (for example if the spatial step `dlon` is 0.5 degree, the first column of my array correspond to longitude 0deg, the second longitude 0.5 deg, the third 1.0deg, etc...).

```
sizeLon     = (lonMax-lonMin)/dlon  
sizeLat     = (latMax-latMin)/dlat
Mp          = numpy.ma.masked_array(zeros((sizeLat,sizeLon)),mask=True)
for rows in zip(LST,LAT,LON):
    for lstVal, latVal,lonVal in zip(*rows):
        if lstVal is not numpy.ma.masked:
            lp  = round(-(latVal-latMin)/dlat)
            cp  = round((lonVal-lonMin)/dlon)
            Mp[lp,cp] = lstVal
```

Comment: What is the operation you are trying to do? Most of the time in Matlab and numpy you run a vectorized version of the function on the array, rather than iterating through the elements

Comment: I am re-projecting some geographical data. So for every single element, I have first to check if the value is not in a masked data area, and then I have to compute the position of this data point in a new matrix.
So I do not think I can use vectorised functions for that.

Comment: @Gulux is the masked data also available as a numpy array? If so could you paste an example? If you can write out a tiny example and what you are trying to achieve there is often a way to do it in a couple of lines of numpy :) See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10178823/553404) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5795700/553404) for some examples of how to provide data-as-code

Comment: I added some details, and my code, in the question. But I cannot post data here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

For example,

```
>>> a = ['foo', 'bar', 'foorbar']
>>> for i, name in enumerate(a):
...     print 'item %d is %s' % (i, name)
... 
item 0 is foo
item 1 is bar
item 2 is foorbar
```

If you do not actually need the `i`, `j` values but only the corresponding entries in another matrix, you might want to consider just [zipping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the rows:

```
>>> b = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> x = [['foo', 'bar'], ['barFoo', 'fooBar']]
>>> for rows in zip(b, x):
...     for bval, xval in zip(*rows):
...         print 'bval: %d; xval: %s' % (bval, xval)
... 
bval: 1; xval: foo
bval: 2; xval: bar
bval: 3; xval: barFoo
bval: 4; xval: fooBar
```

Comment: Wow, I never heard about this zip(), but it works like a charm! The execution time of my script dropped from 1-2 minutes to 12 seconds!
I adopt it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're looking for might be `enumerate()`, which [provides you](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the index of the value in the collection that you're iterating over along with the value:

`for i, line in enumerate(data):
    for j, elt in enumerate(line):
        if not elt == 0:
            <operations>`